# log returns the result of a fun function

Tags: oracle

I have a function that returns the amount of a term saver, but the code that I have, the system returns an error.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moneysaving 
    RETURN number 
    IS
    moineysaving_p number(10);  
    BEGIN
      select  customer_id , case  
      when periods_id = "TK12" then
         case 
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =12
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.063/365*365))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >12 || TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <24 
           then TRUNC((money *(1+0.063/365*365))+(money *(1+0.003/365*365)))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=24
           then TRUNC((money *(1+0.063/365*365))+(money *(1+0.06/365*365)))
         end 
        when   periods_id = "TK6" then 
         case
          when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =6
          then TRUNC(money *(1+0.054/365*365)))
          when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >6 || TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <12
          then TRUNC((money *(1+0.054/365*365))+(money *(1+0.3/365*365)))
          when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=12
          then TRUNC((money *(1+0.054/365*365))+(money *(1+0.054/365*365)))
         end
        when   periods_id = "TK3" then 
          case
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =3
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.05/365*365)))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >3|| TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <6
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.05/365*365))+(money *(1+0.003/365*365)))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=6
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.05/365*365))+(money *(1+0.05/365*365)))
          end
        when   periods_id = "TK1" then
          case
            when  TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =1
            then TRUNC(money *(1+0.045/365*365)))
            when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >1 || TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <3
            then TRUNC(money *(1+0.045/365*365))+money *(1+0.003/365*365)))
            when  TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=3
            then TRUNC(money *(1+0.045/365*365))+money *(1+0.045/365*365)))
          end 
        else TRUNC(money *(1+0.003/365*365))
      end 
      from saving ;
    RETURN moineysaving_p;
    END;
```

You have some money deposited in the bank for the term registered, you come get the money by term, and calculate the amount you received when depositing over that term, ora-00695, ora-001765

Comment: Assuming that the `saving` table can have multiple rows, your `select` statement will raise a `too_many_rows` exception because there is no predicate.  I would expect that you want your function to take a parameter that is used as a predicate to the `select` statement which filters the data down to a single row.  Otherwise, you would need to do something to either aggregate the multiple rows that match the non-existent predicate into a single result or fetch the results into a collection that you then further process to produce a scalar result.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated.

Use single quotes '' instead of double quotes "".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moneysaving 
    RETURN number 
    IS
    moineysaving_p number(10);  
    BEGIN
      select  customer_id , case  
      when periods_id = 'TK12' then
         case 
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =12
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.063/365*365))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >12 || TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <24 
           then TRUNC((money *(1+0.063/365*365))+(money *(1+0.003/365*365)))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=24
           then TRUNC((money *(1+0.063/365*365))+(money *(1+0.06/365*365)))
         end 
        when   periods_id = 'TK6' then 
         case
          when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =6
          then TRUNC(money *(1+0.054/365*365)))
          when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >6 || TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <12
          then TRUNC((money *(1+0.054/365*365))+(money *(1+0.3/365*365)))
          when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=12
          then TRUNC((money *(1+0.054/365*365))+(money *(1+0.054/365*365)))
         end
        when   periods_id = 'TK3' then 
          case
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =3
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.05/365*365)))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >3|| TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <6
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.05/365*365))+(money *(1+0.003/365*365)))
           when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=6
           then TRUNC(money *(1+0.05/365*365))+(money *(1+0.05/365*365)))
          end
        when   periods_id = 'TK1' then
          case
            when  TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) =1
            then TRUNC(money *(1+0.045/365*365)))
            when TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >1 || TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) <3
            then TRUNC(money *(1+0.045/365*365))+money *(1+0.003/365*365)))
            when  TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (sentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE ( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy/mm/dd'))) >=3
            then TRUNC(money *(1+0.045/365*365))+money *(1+0.045/365*365)))
          end 
        else TRUNC(money *(1+0.003/365*365))
      end 
      from saving ;
    RETURN moineysaving_p;
    END;
```